# why can't I send 1 ether to another account via smartcontract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am building a contract with Solidity and deployed it to Ethereum private network `Ropsten`. There is a `payRequest` method which transfers 1 ether to another account. I have deployed the contact and run the method successfully. (I set the recipient address and 1 as amount)

I am able to view the transaction hash in Etherscan and its status is success. But the `success` in the response is false.

The value in the transaction is 0. The recipient address doesn't receive this transfer as well. What did I do wrong?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.7.4;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Leger {
    struct TransferRequest {
        string title;
        uint256 amount;
        string bsb;
        string accountName;
        string accountNumber;
    }

    event PaymentReceive(address from, uint256 amount);
    event TransactionBytes(bytes transactionBytes);
    event RequestPaid(address receiver, uint256 amount);

    function payRequest(address payable _recipient, uint256 _amount) public {
        
        (bool success, bytes memory transactionBytes) = _recipient.call{value:_amount}('');
        
        emit TransactionBytes(transactionBytes);
        
        emit RequestPaid(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    receive() external payable {
        emit PaymentReceive(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the address of your contract in ropsten?, maybe see the internal tx could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not payable, please use:

```
function payRequest(address payable _recipient, uint256 _amount)payable public {
        
        (bool success, bytes memory transactionBytes) = _recipient.call{value:_amount}('');
        
        emit TransactionBytes(transactionBytes);
        
        emit RequestPaid(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
```

I don't see from which account the ether are from.
You don't declare your variables in the contract (for example before the event as done in the best practices).

To be fully transparent, your contract seems strange or incomplete to me.

Comment: I added the `payable` keyword in the function but still the same issue. Do you know how I can specify which account the ether are from?

Comment: The way you do it is like the contract send money and there is no _recipient.transfer(_amount)

Comment: what do you mean by `there is no _recipient.transfer(_amount)`? The `_recipient` is a pass in address parameter and I use `call` method to transfer. Do you mean I need to change from `call` to `transfer` method?

Comment: This is the recommended method to use when you're just sending Ether via calling the fallback function.